# Atlassian Bamboo: Continuously run a plan

Tags: bamboo, continuous-deployment

I have configured a plan bamboo to build a project. This plan first checkout the latest code from SVN and executes a command to build the project. Building of this project takes 4hrs-5hrs. I want my plan to run continuously i.e if the plan creates one build then immediately bamboo should start another build. I want the event to start building a project should completion of previous build not commiting something in to svn. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: So basically you want to hit build, then have it build. Then when it is finished building to build again and to have this loop repeat forever? Even if there are no new changes between builds? Or are you just looking to have the build run if there are any pending SVN changes that haven't been built yet?

Comment: yes to your first two questions. Because the project has lot of work now and people are checking small changes to trunk. I dont want my build to get stuck up for 4-5hrs for small changes so i am hoping after 4-5 hrs there will be many changes to picked and it can build at once

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled trigger with a cron expression causing your plan to build every X minutes. X should then be <= the estimated build time. Disadvantage may be that it can cause to have multiple builds in the build queue after a while.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would do the following.

In the plan settings you can set the maximum number of builds to be 1 at an time.
Then configure the queue to be maximum of 1.
This way only a single build will build with only a single job in the queue.
Then you can either "set a scheduled trigger with a cron expression causing your plan to build every X minutes"

or make a final step do a commit to the repo when if you have a change driven trigger it would immediately run another job as it would detect a change.